# Question on showing function is lower semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

A function is lower semicontinuous at $x \in\mathbb{R}$ if given any sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$,
$$f(x)\leq\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$$

Provided that the limit on the right exists.

Let $$I_{u}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \quad x > 0 \\ 0, & \quad x \leq 0 \end{cases}$$

Show $I_u(x)$ is lower semicontinuous.

Attempt:Let $x_n$ be any sequence that converges to $0$.Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_u(x_n)=0$ or
$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_u(x_n)=1$.

In either case $I_u(0)=0\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}  I_u(x_n)$.

Is this argument correct or do I have to show why $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_u(x_n)=0$ or
$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_u(x_n)=1$?

Comment: Your definition of lower semi-continuity seems incomplete. What if $x_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ for instance, in what way does $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{u}(x_{n})$ make sense? I believe to correct it you need $f(x)\leq \lim \inf_{n\to \infty} f(x_{n})$ for lower semi-continuity.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski I have added a line that I believe makes the question well posed now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition, your argument is correct. It would make the argument more complete if you, as mentioned, added why only $0$ and $1$ are the limits if they exist (although obvious).

As for the definition, you will have to be careful in applying it further. Continuity at $x$ for $f$ in terms of sequences is that for any sequence $(x_{n})$ with $x_{n}\to x$ we have $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$, but, if you define upper semi-continuity in a similar way then for a upper and lower semi-continuous function $g$ there could exist a sequence $(y_{n})$ with $y_{n} \to y$ but $g(y_{n})$ does not converge to $g(y)$. That is, $g$ would not be continuous.